# how can i copy file in order to MTP (Android phone)?

Tags: command-line, android, file-transfer, sd-card, mtp

i am trying to copy .mp3 files in order

to my phone but it windows copies them from the first one (the one on the top of the list ) to the last one

so in searching for a solution i found this program [CopyInOrder](http://www.compulsivecode.com/project_copyinorder.aspx)

after i choose the files i press on create .bat file in the program 
i reverse the lines order in bat file using [sort text lines site](https://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/sort-text-lines/)

so i can copy from the oldest to the newest  but the only one problem is that i can't choose the sd card from my MTP ..
even i can't access it using CMD ...
and i have tried to insert my phone as sd card only but when i unplugs the phone the order of the new files gets messed up again

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dev fixed the problem now the program works :)